# Event vs Delegates

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a delegate and events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-is-the-difference-between-a-delegate-and-events)
>
> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between events and delegates and its  respective applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563549/difference-between-events-and-delegates-and-its-respective-applications)

I am little confuse about use of event and delegate, what is difference between these two and where I should use what ?

Comment: @Firoz: Didn't you find any of the example on the web on this topic, easily understandable?