# Could anyone please explain how action differs from event in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Could anyone please explain the difference between using action and events in c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431359/event-action-vs-event-eventhandler or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282476/actiont-vs-delegate-event or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750628/action-vs-event-action

Comment: You should read Jon Skeet's article labeled [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

Comment: In short, both are delegates, but `EventHandler<T>` is designed specifically for handling events and `Action<T...>` is a more general purpose delegate for all other situations where no return type is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In short: an Action is a single callback / delegate. An event is multicast callback / delegate. So while an Action can call only one handler an event can have multiple handlers.

**Event-Sample:**

```
// Subscribe
MyEvent += MyMethod1;
MyEvent += MyMethod2;

// Unsubscribe
MyEvent -= MyMethod1;
MyEvent -= MyMethod2;
```

If the event MyEvent gets raised/called both methods (MyMethod1 and MyMethod2) get called. You can not use += operator for actions.

**Action-Sample:**

```
MyAction = MyMethod3;
```

Actions are mainly used for some local callback mechanism. For example accept a parameter of Type `Action<>`. If an action should have a result one can use `Func<>` instead `Action<>`. Both are handy for a API that accepts Lambda's.

If a class expose some general "callback" they should be exposed as regular events.