# EventHandler and Delegate misunderstanding

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Please take a look at the code below, which works as I would expect:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Delegate Sub TestEventHandler(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim alhandler As TestEventHandler = AddressOf TestEventMethod
    Public Event Test1 As TestEventHandler
    Public Event Test2 As TestEventHandler

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AddHandler Me.Test1, alhandler
        AddHandler Me.Test2, alhandler
        RaiseEvent Test1(Me, e)
        RaiseEvent Test2(Me, e)
        RemoveHandler Me.Test1, alhandler
        RaiseEvent Test1(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestEventMethod(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("Test")
    End Sub


End Class
```

I am confused with the two statements below:

```
Dim alhandler As TestEventHandler = AddressOf TestEventMethod '1
Public Event Test1 As TestEventHandler '2
```

> 1) This is saying that the reference of alHandler is a delegate that
>   points to the address of a function. 2) This is saying that Test1 is
>   an event of type Delegate.  How can an event and a handler be a
>   delegate?

Comment: An Event Handler is just a particular `type` of delegate.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, thanks.  What are the other types of delegates?

Comment: The ones that are not Event Handlers. :)  You can define a delegate type having any signature you want.  However, since you asked, here's another example defined in the Framework: [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

Comment: Is the Test1 variable an event or a delegate or both?

Comment: All Events are delegates, but Events have a specific signature and compiler support. You can `RaiseEvent`, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [could someone explain to me what exactly is an event and what is the difference with delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890791/could-someone-explain-to-me-what-exactly-is-an-event-and-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, each type of delegate is a type, just as if it were a regular class.  So, in your example code, `TestEventHandler` is a delegate type.  A `TestEventHandler` variable can reference any `TestEventHandler` object, just like any other variable can reference any object of its own type.  `TestEventHandler` objects must be instantiated, just like objects of any other type.

Delegates are special, however, in that you declare them using a different, special, syntax.  For instance, if you had the following method:

```
Public Sub MyMethod(Text As String)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

You could create a delegate that matches that method signature like this:

```
Public Delegate Sub MyMethodDelegate(Text As String)
```

Remember, by doing so, that simply defines the `MyMethodDelegate` type.  That doesn't declare a variable of that type nor does it instantiate an object of that type.

There are two things in VB.NET syntax, however, which often cause a lot of confusion.  First, when you declare an event, you can use two different syntax:

```
Public Event MyEvent As MyMethodDelegate
Public Event MyEvent(Text As String)
```

Both of those lines do the same thing.  The first line defines the event using an already defined delegate type.  The second line essentially defines a new unnamed delegate on the fly and then uses it as the type for the event.  *(Note, I'm using the `MyMethodDelegate` for simplicity, and that will work, but standards dictate that events should have a sender and an event args.)*  When an event is declared, think of it like a variable.  Behind the scenes, it's really like a collection object that keeps a list of all the delegate objects that are added to it using the `AddHandler` function.

The second confusing thing in VB.NET is that the compiler will automatically instantiate a new delegate object for you, if necessary, when you use the `AddressOf` function.  So, for instance, when you do something like this:

```
AddHandler myObject.MyEvent, AddressOf MyMethod
```

It's just a shortcut for typing the full text, like this:

```
AddHandler myObject.MyEvent, New MyMethodDelegate(AddressOf MyMethod)
```

The latter, in my opinion is much more clear.  What you are actually doing is creating a new object of that delegate type and pointing that delegate object to that method, and then adding that delegate object to the event (that event collection-like variable defined by the object's type).

So, in your example, this line:

```
Dim alhandler As TestEventHandler = AddressOf TestEventMethod
```

Would be more clearly written as:

```
Dim alhandler As TestEventHandler = New TestEventHandler(AddressOf TestEventMethod)
```

It's declaring a delegate variable and then setting it to a new delegate object that points to that particular method.  In this case, it's just a standard delegate variable, not an event.  Events are very similar to delegates field/properties.  Events are essentially an accessor wrapper around a private delegate field, in the same way that properties often wrap a private field.  The big differences between delegate fields and events are that events support the `AddHandler` and `EventHandler` functions and events cannot be raised/invoked from outside of the class that defines it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have posted another question about asynchronous calls and delegates here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091839/executing-a-callback-method-when-an-asynchronous-call-completes, if you have time.