# keyword event in c#

Tags: c#, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need the “event” keyword while defining events ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events)

in the MSDN exemple : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w369ty8x(v=VS.80).aspx

If i delete the event keyword from the publisher class, my project work. so wy we add the key word event.

thanks

Comment: To make this a question  you'll have to show what does _not_ work with the event keyword. Now it looks like you solved one error by making another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `encapsulation`. If keyword 'event' will be removed then you will be able to invoke 'event' and even change it's subscriptions from external classes which do not own the event. See Jon's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393552/what-is-the-difference-between-delegate-and-event-in-c/5393588#5393588). With `event` keyword you're sharing an event, without it you're giving an access to `delegate`.