# What's the difference between delegate,event and method?

Tags: c#

(analogy would be very helpful). The answer so far on this topic either lacking the three subjects or are not clear enough for me.

Comment: a quick search would answer this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a delegate and events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-is-the-difference-between-a-delegate-and-events)

Comment: This topic is really good explained by the MSDN. Have you even tried searching the web? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt.aspx and much more MSDN links provide a lot of information on delegates and events

Answer (score 5):

Method = a function in a class.

Delegate = a pointer to a Method.

Event = a delegate with special restrictions - it can only be invoked by the class that declares it

Answer (score 3):

**Method** - a function with some logic.

**Delegate** - a function pointer. You can think of it as a variable which can reference methods.

**Event** - a collection of delegates, which you can execute/invoke at will.

Answer (score 1):

A [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a member function.

A [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is an object that can hold a member-function.

An [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is, well, an event. With each event there is one associated delegate. All the methods that are held in the delegate are called when the event is fired