# What is the relationship between delegates and events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, c++-cli

`Delegate` does the same job of function pointers. It can be viewed as the function pointers of the managed world. It simply represents the address of a function to call, along with a specific object whose method is to be called.

Many times I read the term `Delegate` along with the term`Event` but I can not see the relationship between them. Is the `Event` a specific type of delegates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between delegates and events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-are-the-differences-between-delegates-and-events)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx). Longer answer:

Events are a pattern *on top* of delegates. They're an implementation of the [publisher/subscriber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern (aka [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)), using delegates as the means of representing a subscription.

Whenever you see something like:

```
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

you should instead think of two methods:

```
public void AddFooHandler(EventHandler handler) { ... }
public void RemoveFooHandler(EventHandler handler) { ... }
```

All that a client from the outside can do is subscribe and unsubscribe. In particular, the client *cannot* raise the event themselves (without a separate method being provided for that purpose) nor can they "replace" or remove other subscriptions.

Comment: I just have to say - Your short answer is (or links to) 400+ lines and your long answer is 16...

Comment: @Neowizard: Links to being the operative word. I didn't want to *just* give a link, basically.

Answer (score 10):

The answers so far are all very good, but they all explore the "mechanical" side of the relationship. I look at it a bit differently.

Think about the "start" button on a microwave oven. That button provides an abstraction to the user of the microwave, and the button has certain properties. It has size, it has position, it has text, it has an action when pressed.

A `Button` class in a C# program also provides an abstraction, and it similarly has certain properties. Like the microwave button, it has size and position and text and an action when pressed.

The size and position are represented by integers, and the text by a string. One would not say of the microwave oven button that it "has integers representing its size and position and a string representing its text". And for the software button, the fact that it has size and position and text are the *semantics* of the button. The fact that the size and position and text are represented by integers and strings is a fact about the *mechanisms* that the button is built out of, not a fact about the *purpose* of the button or *logically* what information it is presenting to the world.

A software button represents the action of being clicked as an event; the event says "this is a thing that can be clicked".  The collection of delegates that actually respondes when the button is clicked is part of the *mechanism*.

A *property* tells you a fact about a class. It might do so by giving you a string, but do not confuse the string with the property. The string is the *mechanism* that the property uses to communicate the fact to the consumer.  An *event* also tells you a fact about a class. It does so with a *delegate* because a delegate is the *mechanism* that an event is built out of.

Comment: Thinking in terms of meaning rather than mechanics can be useful, but can sometimes lead one to make incorrect assumptions about how things will behave.  In terms of "meaning", I would describe an "event" in .net as "a means by which objects can either ask another object for notification when an expected future event occurs, or inform that other object that notifications are no longer necessary".  An object would normally handle requests for notification by adding them to some sort of collection, but it wouldn't necessarily have to do so.  For example...

Comment: ...if an AcmeJoystick class serves as a concrete implementation of an abstract GameController which exposes a "LeftTriggerPushed" event and the Acme Joystick doesn't have a left trigger, it could simply discard any requests to be notified about the left trigger without bothering to add them to a list.

Answer (score 4):

An event is in essence a container of delegates with a way to trigger them.  The event also provides encapsulation allowing the owner of the event to be the only source triggering registered delegates.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**.

An event is implemented by using delegates(that's why an event looks like a delegate)

**Long Answer**

An event is a message sent by an object to signal the occurrence of an action. The action could be caused by user interaction, such as a mouse click, or it could be triggered by some other program logic. The object that raises the event is called the event sender. The object that captures the event and responds to it is called the event receiver.

In event communication, the event sender class does not know which object or method will receive (handle) the events it raises. What is needed is an intermediary (or pointer-like mechanism) between the source and the receiver. The .NET Framework defines a special type (Delegate) that provides the functionality of a function pointer.

A delegate is a class that can hold a reference to a method. Unlike other classes, a delegate class has a signature, and it can hold references only to methods that match its signature. A delegate is thus equivalent to a type-safe function pointer or a callback. While delegates have other uses, the discussion here focuses on the event handling functionality of delegates. A delegate declaration is sufficient to define a delegate class. The declaration supplies the signature of the delegate, and the common language runtime provides the implementation. The following example shows an event delegate declaration.

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

A `Delegate` is a class which typically holds an object reference, combined with a pointer to a method which is either a static method (in which case the object reference will be `null`) or a method which is guaranteed to work on the type of object included in the delegate.  Invoking a delegate will invoke the indicated method, passing it the contained object if appropriate.  It's also possible for a delegate to hold an array of objects and an array of associated method, in which case invoking the delegate will invoke each method on its corresponding object, aborting the process if an exception occurs.  All delegates, even those with only a single object/method pair, are stored as a type derived from `MulticastDelegate`.

An `Event` is a pair of methods exposed by an object which other code can use to either request that a the object invoke a particular delegate in some expected future circumstance, or inform the object that it no longer needs to invoke that delegate.  Most objects will take the passed-in delegate and add it to a MulticastDelegate, which the object will then invoke when the circumstance arrives (invoking the MulticastDelegate will invoke all its members), but objects are free to implement the event "add" and "remove" accessors however they see fit.

A few additional notes:

1. The event accessor says nothing about the circumstances in which any passed-in delegates will actually be invoked, nor the manner in which that will occur (e.g. whether it will happen on any particular thread).

   Both the C# compiler and vb.net will automatically generate code for "add" and "remove" methods which use a `MulticastDelegate` in the absence of code that does something else.  In C#, the name of the MulticastDelegate will be the same as the name of the event, which can cause some confusion, especially in older C# compilers, where `eventName += someDelegate` would have a different meaning outside the class exposing the event than it would have within it.

   Delegates are immutable, though the objects to which they hold references may not be.  Given two delegates, one can produce a new delegate which combines all the object/method pairs from each; one may also produce a delegate which contains all of the object/method pairs in the first one, except for one which matches the second, though the semantics are rather weird if the second delegate has more than one object/method pair.

   One should avoid passing a `MulticastDelegate` produced via `Delegate.Combine` to an event 'add' handler if there is any possibility that any of the constituent delegates, or other delegates equivalent to them, may also be passed, because many event implementations use `MulticastDelegate` addition and subtraction, and thus suffer from weird "subtract" semantics.

Because point #2 above, the term "event" often gets used, especially in C#, to refer to the auto-generated delegate field associated with an event.  In reality, though, an "event" is not a delegate--it is simply the pair of add and remove methods (in VB, an "event" also encompasses a method, for use only within the class, for purposes of "raising" an event (i.e. invoking the delegates which have been previously passed to the "add" method); this is simply syntactic sugar to allow the syntax `RaiseEvent EventName(params)` to be used as an alternative to calling the appropriate method directly).