# Consequences of missing `event` for delegate type?

Tags: c#, events

I'm beginner to C#, I have code where by accident I declared events skipping `event` keyword. I was sure that this is right code:

```cs
using System;

public class Player
{
    ...
    private float money;
    public Action<float> OnMoneyChanged; // missed `event` keyword.

    private void SetMoney(float amount)
    {
        money = amount;
        OnMoneyChanged?.Invoke(amount);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Level
{
   public Level(Player player)
   {
      player.OnMoneyChanged += UpdateUi;
      ...
   }

   private void UpdateUi(float money)
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

And that's works perfect, no error, no bugs appear.
I knows that formally by skipping `event` I didn't declare events but normal `delegate`.

The only drawback I came out is that this mislead other programmer who will read the code, they may conclude that something strange happening here.

The question is: what are the long consequences of missing `event` for delegate type?
What putting missing `event` keyword changes?

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-are-the-differences-between-delegates-and-events solves all my considerations.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `event` keyword (to Player.OnMoneyChanged), you won't be able to call `Player.OnMoneyChanged.Invoke(...)` outside of the Player class

Comment: I just checked, you right.